# Can dryer ducting be placed near gas line?

Tags: dryer, natural-gas, venting

We are reconfiguring the laundry room on the main level of our house in Toronto, Canada. There is an existing exterior dryer vent but it is on the oppsite side of the room where the dryer will now be located. The mechanical room is directly below the laundry area.

One option that allows us to reuse the existing vent is to run the duct from the dryer through the floor into the mechanical area, across the room under the joists and then up through the floor and ultimately connect to the existing vent.

As you can see from the picture below (only shows a portion of the duct from the floor above - the horizontal section has not been connected) the ducting will end up being fairly close to the gas supply line that enters the mechanical room from outside. Is this an issue and are there any rules for how far apart they need to be?

Any pointers or tips are greatly appreciated. Thx
[image]

Comment: With gas dryers being a thing, I would think that gas lines being next to dryer ducts is fairly common.

Answer (score 2):

Canada may have different rules but it is fairly common to see dryer exhaust vents routed next to gas lines in a garage normally the vent is really not that hot.

Comment: Thanks both for your feedback. It is much appreciated